# Char.Parse("P") returns 80 'P' in C#

Tags: c#, string, char

`Char.Parse("P")` returns `80 'P'` in C#. I need only the 'P' character to be returned.

Comment: It returns only P. you can do Console.Write() to check

Comment: What do you mean returns `80 'P'`? It returns a char, which is `'P'`, likely the debugger is trying to be helpful by showing you the codepoint value as well. Try just `var x = 'P';` and see if that is similar.

Comment: `char.Parse` returns a `char` value, not the `int`. `Int` representation is added by debugger

Comment: What variable type you are are storing the result in? Can you provide example code where you see "80 'P'"

Comment: Just type `'P'` to get the char, instead of doing a string first just to convert to char. - this could help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char

Comment: Hi. If the answer below solved your problem please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`char.Parse()` is returning the value as a char. It's just that the debugger also displays the char's ascii value. You can verify it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(char.Parse("P"));
Console.WriteLine("P".ToCharArray().First());
```

In both cases, it will print the character 'P'.